# How to fix class not found error exception in freetts 1.2.2 VoiceManager in Maven on Windows

Tags: java

I am new to freetts and I want to convert text to speech, but I am getting class not found exception.

My source code

```java
package com.sewonet;

import com.sun.speech.freetts.VoiceManager;
import com.sun.speech.freetts.Voice;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        VoiceManager voiceManager = VoiceManager.getInstance();
        Voice voice = VoiceManager.getVoice("kelvin16");
        voice.speak("I love java");
    }

}
```

Code compilation does not generate any error but generate the below error at runtime.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/speech/freetts/VoiceManager
        at com.sewonet.App.main(App.java:7)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.speech.freetts.VoiceManager
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        ... 1 more
```

Comment: Please someone should help me. I have been trying to fix it but still have not been able to fix it.

Comment: You need to make sure that that class is on the classpath when you run your program.

Comment: Please I am using maven and  I have specified the freetts 1.2.2  dependency in the pom.xml file.

Comment: How are you running your program?

Comment: https://freetts.sourceforge.io/#no_jsapi might help